# MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION - activity not found exception

Tags: android, permissions, overlay, android-permissions

I'm getting following exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION dat=package:com.my.app }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1816)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1525)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4265)
```

This happened in an app that's already a few years old and is working flawlessly. Now I got this exception for an **android 7** device, model **ZUK Z1**. Any ideas? Seems like a problem with the rom. Does this rom offer an alternative way to get overlay drawing permissions?

**Edit - here's the function I use to get permissions**

```
public static void checkOverlayPermission(Activity activity)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(activity))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + activity.getPackageName()));
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, BaseDef.OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
    }
}
```

Comment: what version you running your app that works before. Remember after Android 6.0 Marshmallow, your app need to request permissions(some) during run time. You can no longer request permission on manifest.

Comment: All from android 5 to 7. And if I would not start an activity (like before android 6) I would not get the exception. I added the code above to show you what I do

Comment: Hey @prom85 did you find any solution of this question

Comment: @UltimateDevil I guess we'll never know

Comment: Hi Guys I am having the same issue but on Android TV. Is there a way to get it to work on TV?

Comment: Any fix on Android TV @SKG ?

Comment: I have the same issue on Android 10 API 29. The solution did not work for me. My emulator has crashed with the same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.This is working for me. It may help you

```
if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION");
                localIntent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                localIntent.setFlags(268435456);
                startActivity(localIntent);
            }
```

**Try this if your rom is the issue**

Basically you can't just check all rom which have issues with settings. The code above works fine in android N as well. I tested this myself.

What you can do is put your code inside a try catch block and when you enters the catch block show user a dialog which asks him to give overlay permission manually instead taking him directly to the settings page.

There are some roms basically the custom roms which have issues with some system settings so this is the best approach you can use to tackle these situations.

Comment: not sure why you have`localIntent.setFlags(268435456);` I omitted it and everything works great

Comment: This is exactly what's in Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION. Downvote. Bad practice to manually type in the Action Intent.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
            var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission);
            intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromParts("package", PackageName, null));
            StartActivity(intent);
```

This is in Xamarin tho!